# I'm trying to store values from with a method to an object created earlier

Tags: java, android, class, scope, external

So I'm still relatively new to java and android.  I am trying to figure out if there is a way that I can store 2 values from inside methods of SomeClass to an object.

```
public class MainClass extends ...{

    Output outputObject = new Output();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        SomeClass classTask = new SomeClass(params) {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String output) {
                outputObject.setVarOutput(output);
            }
        }
        classTask1.execute(link);




        SomeClass classTask2 = new SomeClass(params) {
            @Override
            public void processFinish(String output) {
                outputObject.setVar2Output(output);
            }
        }
        classTask2.execute(link2);


        // gather the outputObject values
        //for example
        result = outputObject.getVarOutput() + getVar2Output();
    }
    });
```

I've tried a few things to no avail.  I'm not sure what to look for or into.

Comment: What do you mean by 'gather the outputObject'?

Comment: What is SomeClass? What exactly is trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a way that I can store 2 values from inside methods of SomeClass to an object.

Yes there is.

It is difficult to tell why the code you've provided isn't working for you as the names you've used are very abstract. I can assume

```
execute()
```

will do some computation, maybe on a different thread. If that is the case then you want to avoid touching the same object from different threads.

I can't give better advice without knowing more about what you're trying to do.

Comment: the project involves connecting android app to a mysql database.  SomeClass is the class built to pull from the database.  I'm getting the results I'm looking for through the processFinish, but I haven't figured out how to get it outside of the class call.  I've tried moving the call to another class call designed for output.

Comment: execute is to execute the Async class i believe

Comment: If that is the case then your result will not have what you expect because the computation might have not finished so processFinish() doesn't get called. You'll have to find another way to perform the computation and get the results. Check the AsyncTask documentation on how you're supposed to use it.

Comment: thanks for the help, i woke up this morning with the solution on my mind.  I realized this morning that I can just store the values in sqlite.  It'll solve this problem and then some others as well.

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is that execute() does not go down the expected path and processFinish() is not called as expected.  Can't know for sure without seeing the details of SomeClass.

Second, this isn't thread-safe from a long shot, because simultaneous onCreate() calls are going to result in both threads trying to update the object at the same time.  Can't guarantee what you'll get, it's a race condition, but as soon as you mentioned database my ears perked up.

Now, if you make outputObject stored in thread-local storage, then at least concurrency isn't a problem, but if it's not the same thread reading as populating the objects, that's not going to work either.  Of course, you could synchronize on outputObject, so you get your concurrency at the loss of scalability.

For me, the best solution is one where you create a unique outputObject per onCreate() call and figure out a way to get the data base to the outside world (which maybe isn't necessary since you're dumping the data right there)